# How do I create array adapter with Image array

Tags: java, android

I have 2 arrays like:

Array 1 :

```
String[] web = {"Google Plus","Twitter","Windows","Bing","Itunes","Wordpress","Drupal"} ;
```

Array 2 :

```
String[] webimage = {"@drawable/img1","@drawable/img2","@drawable/img3","@drawable/img4","@drawable/img5","@drawable/img6","@drawable/img7"} ;
```

And I want to create `ArrayAdapter` that uses my Array1 for `TextView` and uses Array2 for icon of row

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView,array);
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you clarify?

Comment: Instead of using Array2, use reflection.

Comment: @Jost : I want create array adapter that each row show image in Array1 and text in Array2

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class to hold the String and the drawable resource

```
public class Item{

    private final String text;
    private final int icon;

    public Item(final String text, final int icon){
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon(final Context context){
        return context.getResources().getDrawable(this.icon)
    }
}
```

and then create an array of Items

```
Item[] items = new Item[1];
item[0] = new Item("Google Plus",R.drawable.img1);
//...etc
```

create a custom ArrayAdapter for Item

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private Context context;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, Item[] items) {
        super(context, 0, items);

        this.context = context;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        Item item = getItem(position);    

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
        }

        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvText.setText(item.getText());
        ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.getDrawable(this.context));

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In the example above `R.layout.item_row` is a layout that you would have to create containing a `TextView` with id `tvText` and an ImageView with id `ivIcon`.